# Statistically comparing two sets of coordinates

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, spatial-statistics

I have been given a task to compare two sets of points, one set being a set of predetermined points, on the other being a set of actual points that were taken in the field.

I have to compare these two sets and come up with the statistical difference between the two sets using qgis.

Could someone recommend a process I could go through to achieve this?

Comment: What kind of comparison(s) are you interested in? For example, it could just be a comparison of the number of points; their tendency for clustering; etc. There are lots of possibilities, too many to list. More information is needed to help you out.

Comment: are the points supposed to make geographical pairs or are the locations independantly selected.